# Where is Stat_t defined for plan9?

Tags: go, stat, plan-9

In the `plan9` specific Go code for `syscall`, there is no `Stat_t` like with other `GOOS`. Where is `Stat_t`, or its equivalent defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: It's the [`*syscall.Dir`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dir_plan9.go#L25) type. Read on for details.

The source for `os.Stat` on Plan9 is [here](https://golang.org/src/os/file_plan9.go#L162). It calls `dirstat`, which is defined [here](https://golang.org/src/os/stat_plan9.go?#L44). It feeds the return value of `dirstat` into `fileInfoFromStat`, which is defined in the same file [here](https://golang.org/src/os/stat_plan9.go?#L20).

In the case of paths (as opposed to `*File` objects), `dirstat` just calls [`syscall.Stat`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_plan9.go#L337), which is basically just a thin wrapper around [`stat`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/zsyscall_plan9_amd64.go#L105). `syscall.Stat` expects a byte buffer to be able to write into. This buffer is processed a bit (see `dirstat` for details), and then fed into [`syscall.UnmarshalDir`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dir_plan9.go#L98), which is where the magic happens. The documentation states that it "decodes a single 9P stat message" from a buffer and returns a [`*syscall.Dir`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dir_plan9.go#L25).

`dirstat` then passes this `*syscall.Dir` to `fileInfoFromStat`, which is what processes it into a `FileInfo`. It's this `*syscall.Dir` value that is obtained through the `Sys()` method on the `FileInfo` object.