# undefined: syscall.Stat_t for plan9

Tags: go, plan-9

I am working on a file manager for 9front/Plan9; dev work is done in Go v1.15 under 64-bit Ubuntu with cross-compilation to build Plan9 binaries.

Let's assume a function to retrieve user/group information:

```
import "syscall"
func GetXid(info os.FileInfo) (string, string) {
    UID := "N/A"
    GID := "N/A"
    if stat, ok := info.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t); ok {
        UID = strconv.Itoa(int(stat.Uid))
        GID = strconv.Itoa(int(stat.Gid))
    }
    return UID, GID
}
```

it fails during Plan9 compilation with `undefined: syscall.Stat_t`.

`syscall` [package page](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) states that it has been deprecated since Go v1.4 and replaced with OS-specific repos under `golang.org/x/sys/`.

- How to implement OS-specific casting of the `os.FileInfo.Sys` for Linux and Plan9

Comment: Note that plan9 does not have user and group *IDs* but rather user and group *names* (strings). So the way to handle this as portably as possible, while supporting plan9, is to expand the IDs to names (strings) on Linux. I don't know about the rest of this though.

Comment: `golang.org/x/sys/plan9` is not part of the go installation. The link you show is just the sys repo that contains that package. If you don’t have it it’s because you didn’t import it.

Comment: @torek i am open to handling the return value as `string`; the question is - how to implement instructions that will reference one function OR logic for Plan9 compilation and another for Linux?

Comment: The general mechanism for that is the `+build` directive. You define some sort of "universal accessor", then write Go files for each OS to define a function that returns the right values for that OS. Then you `+build` each of those Go files only for that one OS. They all define the same function with the same arguments, so your portable code can now call that one function.

Comment: @torek Thank you! I have moved the OS-specific codebase into separate files (as illustrated by the updated posting). The compilation now passes. However, another issue manifested - how to perform OS-specific "casting" of the `os.FileInfo.Sys`

Comment: Unfortunately the stuff in `info.Sys()` is quite messy. If you look in the Go source, in the `src/syscall` directory, you'll see that there are a bunch of `ztypes_*_*.go` files, each of which defines a `Stat_t`: these are the OS-specific `Stat_t` types that an info `Sys` accesses (if it doesn't just return nil, that is). You'll see that each of these files also has a `+build` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545178) greatly aided my research. In short, while the `syscall` codebase was broken and moved into OS-specific packages under `golang.org/x/sys/`, we still use `syscall.xxx` semantic to access structures from `golang.org/x/sys/`:

- for Plan9 it is [Dir](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dir_plan9.go)

```
var info os.FileInfo = ...
info.Sys().(*syscall.Dir)
```

- for Linux it is [Stat_t](https://golang.org/src/syscall/ztypes_linux_amd64.go)

```
var info os.FileInfo = ...
info.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
```

To put the above findings into the solution, I followed @torek advice and created two files, each with the `func GetXid(info os.FileInfo) (string, string)` function and `// +build <os>` instruction at the top:

- file_details_plan9.go

```
// +build plan9

package model
import (
    "syscall"
    "os"
)

func GetXid(info os.FileInfo) (string, string) {
    UID := "N/A"
    GID := "N/A"
    if stat, ok := info.Sys().(*syscall.Dir); ok {
        UID = stat.Uid
        GID = stat.Gid
    }
    return UID, GID
}
```

- file_details_unix.go

```
// +build linux

package model
import (
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
)

func GetXid(info os.FileInfo) (string, string) {
    UID := "N/A"
    GID := "N/A"
    if stat, ok := info.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t); ok {
        UID = strconv.Itoa(int(stat.Uid))
        GID = strconv.Itoa(int(stat.Gid))
    }
    return UID, GID
}
```

**NOTE:** it also appears that the package `golang.org/x/sys/plan9` is missing in the standard Go installation, and needs to be installed explicitly:

```
go get golang.org/x/sys/plan9
go mod vendor
go mod tidy
```